# stream() method does not work in android

Tags: android, android-studio, collections, lambda, java-8

How can I convert this statement from classic java to android

```
Collection<Integer> p1;   
int sum = p1.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

I integrate Java 8 and lambda to my android application, but it still does not work. The method stream() does not found in android.

Can you help me?

Comment: No, I don't ask about the possibility of using java 8 because I am already use it: I ask about an equivalent method of stream() in android

Comment: So you want a `for` loop?

Comment: I want to convert all the statement because one the stream() method is not available, mapToInt() and sum() are not available too.

Comment: Are you looking for https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html ?

Comment: A possibility is to use the streamsupport (https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport) library that backports the streams API to java 6/7.

Comment: @tome Well, streamsupport is actually on sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/ The github project is a mirror.

Comment: @StefanZobel sorry for the mistake and thanks for creating the library!

Comment: @tome Thank you for your response that helps me!

Comment: @tome Now that it is clear what user_1978 is asking for you should probably post this as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) library which backports the stream API to Java 6/7 which can be used for Android development, supported on all devices.

Afaik, this library fully backports the original implementation present in Java 8 and makes it available in a separate package (prefix java8.). The added default methods on the Collection interface (e.g. #stream(), #forEach()) are available from separate utility classes, e.g. Iterables or StreamSupport.

Comment: Does it have a maven repo for Gradle, or must we use physical jar files?

Comment: @Igor Ganapolsky The jars are on Maven Central. No problem to use them from Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Stream API is included in a recent revision of Android 7.0 SDK Platform (API 24):

```
public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E> {
    // .. redacted
    default Stream<E> stream() { .. }
}
```

Please note that in order to use it you have to set `minSdkVersion` to 24.

Comment: Do you know, may be it is possible somehow to run such api with minSdk<24? By example with Jack compiler or sth. There should be some way to backport it, i proud)

Comment: @Beloo I haven't tried by myself, but it seems like steamsupport library that [T.Neidhart mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37880098/1233652) does exactly what you need. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Beloo Yes, streamsupport should work for you. I haven't yet tried it with Jack, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work. A lot of people in the Android world have used it with the retrolambda plugin, but Jack should be just fine.

Comment: Setting `minSdkVersion 24` would render the majority of Android devices incompatible.