# Is Android N Stream API backported to lower versions?

Tags: java, android, lambda, java-stream, android-7.0-nougat

Latest version of Android N has stream package but when i'm trying to use it is saying min Sdk version which i should use is 24 (N) and my min SDK is 16.

I enabled JackOptions with which Lambda expressions , Method References are working fine ( even for versions less than N minsdk) but still has problem is only with Stream package . The link below  https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html says lambda, method references are available to 23 n lower also but no clarity on Stream package.

So i want to understand that Steam package i cannot use in my project ( minsdk 16) ? Or am I missing something .

All sdk components are updated . 
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 24   (23 doesn't matter )

Please suggest me what i should do . Also i saw streamsupport https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport which is working fine but i don't want to add a new dependency.

Comment: As far as I know, not in Android SDK < 24. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854239/stream-method-does-not-work-in-android/37880098 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039566/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-features-optional-and-stream-for-android-14-and-hig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Android N Stream API backported to lower versions?

No, it is not, at least in terms of literally using `java` and `javax` packages, such as `java.util.stream`. No classes get backported to their original Java packages, as otherwise there are namespace collisions on newer devices.

To date, Google has not released some sort of workalike classes for `java.util.stream`, etc., as a library, where those classes happen to use a separate Java package.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Google should have done better than this to support stream like how stream support library has done .    As of now its ridiculous to keep minsdk as 24 for this to work ( without any dependency ).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Google has not backported the Java 8 streams API to lower API versions.  This means there currently is no `AppCompatStream` or anything of that sort.
However, It is possible to use Java 8 Stream API on Android `minSdkVersion` < 24 if you are willing to use 3rd party libraries in your project.  Here are several such open source projects (shout out to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515035/is-it-possible-to-use-the-java-8-stream-api-on-android-api-24) post):

[Lightweight Stream API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API)

[Solid](https://github.com/konmik/solid)

[StreamSupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/)

If you aren't interested in adding another gradle dependency, there is always the possibility of adding the whole project as another module in your Android Studio project, or even as another package in your app's module.